# DbContext getting disposed when load increases (During load testing)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, idisposable

Our project is creating DbContext in a Base class and all other data access layers inherit from it. The Base class implements IDisposable and handles all the dispose work. In normal flow everything works but during load testing we start to get

```
"Exception type: System.InvalidOperationException

Message       : The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
"
```

Any dispose is not handled in child classes and one data access layer also calls other data access layers constantly to reuse DAL methods.

**Base Class :**

```
  public class DataAccessBase : IDisposable
    {

        protected DbDataContext dataContext = null;

        public DataAccessBase()
        {
            dataContext = new DbDataContext();
        }


        public DataAccessBase(DbDataContext dataContext)
        {
            if (dataContext==null )
                dataContext = new DbDataContext();

            this.dataContext = dataContext;
        }

        // NOTE: Leave out the finalizer altogether if this class doesn't 
        // own unmanaged resources itself, but leave the other methods
        // exactly as they are. 
        ~DataAccessBase()
        {
            // Finalizer calls Dispose(false)
            Dispose(false);
        }

        // Dispose() calls Dispose(true)
        public void Dispose()
        {

            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        // The bulk of the clean-up code is implemented in Dispose(bool)
        protected  virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // free managed resources
            }
            // get rid of unmanaged resources
            if (dataContext != null)
            {
                dataContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Using in Child class as :

```
 public class HelpDataAccess : DataAccessBase
    {


        public Help GetHelpRecords (int id)
        {
            try
            {

                return dataContext.Help.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Id == id && h.IsActive);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

           //other methods


    }
```

So this type of simple fetch methods are failing with the DbContext disposed error.

```
Stack Trace : 

Exception type: System.InvalidOperationException

Message       : The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Stacktrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.CreateObjectQuery(Boolean asNoTracking, Nullable`1 streaming, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.InitializeUnderlyingTypes(EntitySetTypePair pair)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

-We tried lot of suggestion but nothing is helping as such.
Any idea why this might happen ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is there any tool available which we can use to trace the error ?

Comment: How are you calling `GetHelpRecords`?

Comment: You can try logging information to some persistent storage most probably txt file.  `DbContextInstance.Database.Log` Action will be invoke passing the string so you would have trace about what is happeing with DbContext instance. You would just need to assign method talking string input to `DbContextInstance.Database.Log`

Comment: @MikeNorgate  : We call it from Business Layer. 

In Business Layer Class we instantiate HelpDataAcess and then call the method as below:

HelpDataAccess help = new HelpDataAccess ();
var records = help.GetHelp();

Comment: @VishalAnand do you always create a new instance directly before calling `GetHelp`? When do you dispose `HelpDataAccess`?

Comment: @MikeNorgate : Yes, If we have to call GetHelp(), we always create the instance of HelpDataAcess  and then call GetHelp(); More over in some part of code, just to avoid duplicate coding we have created  instance of DataAccess Class in some other DataAccess class.

For example : If DA and DB are two separate Data Access class inheriting from DataAccessBase, we have calls of methods of DA from DB and vice-versa so that we don't have to write code again.

When do we dispose HelpDataAccess ? we actually rely on the GC for that matter, we not doing any dispose manually. 
Do you see anything wrong?